# How to sort collection by array?

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, collections

How to sort given collection

```
Collection {
    #items: array:3 [
        0   => MenuPosition,    // ->label = "About Us"
        1   => MenuPosition,    // ->label = "Homepage"
        2   => MenuPosition     // ->label = "Shop"
    ]
}
```

with help of this array

```
$correctOrder = [
    'Homepage',
    'Shop',
    'About Us'
];
```

So in the end i will get

```
Collection {
#items: array:3 [
    0   => MenuPosition,    // ->label = "Homepage"
    1   => MenuPosition,    // ->label = "Shop"
    2   => MenuPosition     // ->label = "About Us"
]
```

MenuPosition is an instance of Eloquent's model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$collection` holds the menu items, try this one:

```
$collection = 
    /*
    Collection {
        #items: array:3 [
            0   => MenuPosition,
            1   => MenuPosition,
            2   => MenuPosition
        ]
    }
    */

$correctOrder = [
    'Homepage',
    'Shop',
    'About Us'
];

$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function($menuItem, $key) use ($correctOrder) {
    return array_search($menuItem->label, $correctOrder);
});
```

[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) gives you the index of the value in an array.

Keep in mind the `label` of the collection and the value in the `$correctOrder` need to be of the same case for this to work. Not a very flexible approach, though, as the names might change.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very simple and will be even simpler when converted into Collection macro :)

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

You can achieve this using `combine()`. From the docs:

> The combine method combines the keys of the collection with the values of another array or collection

So take the indices as the keys from the $correctOrder array and map the Collection against those.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-combine

Comment: Nope, pretty sure he means sorting a collection *by the given array*, so `$somePointlessOrder`.

Comment: Hard to say without an example of what exactly he's trying to sort.

Comment: I changed my question to more correct case with example